# "unknow database" even though i have created database correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly-10

I'm working on java web application. i'm using jboss wildfly 10.x server, and hibernate for persistence. Problem is when i start server it says there is a `unknow database "DATABASE"` which i did not create and not give a name about `DATABASE` anywhere but if i create `DATABASE` it works and fill my correct database.

here is my *-ds.xml:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/atlantisDS"
        pool-name="atlantisPool">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/atlantis?characterEncoding=UTF8
        </connection-url>
        <driver>mysql</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>were</user-name>
            <password>142536</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

here is persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="atlantisPU" transaction-type="JTA">        
   <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/atlantisDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
           <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have looked for `DATABASE` every `*.xml` files but i could not get a clue.
so what is problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: what is xxx ? Is it complaining about ExampleDS ? share error stack

Comment: i have edited question but simple `xxx` is the databasename in the error stack, `xxx` just variable for any DB. it is second DB that  i don't want to create.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have added this line

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/atlantisDS</jta-data-source>
```

it tells container that look for datasource in jboss config file or *-ds.xml

so open your jboss's standalone file and look for code something like this or in your *-ds.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/sampleDS" pool-name="sampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.155.110:3306/databasename</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        <password>root</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

you have defined database name as **atlantis**

Database must exist in Mysql 
whether or not to create tables automatically is optional